# to test the post api testing with different parameter it show the invalid parameter in one csv file

Tags: jmeter

[image]

In the config data set config I put file Name csv file contain all parameter, it read that also when column is blank.

I want that the column which is blank it should skip that column ,when I run In HTTP request where I put the parameter it gives invalid parameter.

How can empty column be ignored?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Add If Controller as a parent to Sampler

If Condition will be `"${parameter } == ""`